# How to fix nginx problem problem with Golang?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Go server with simple JSON request and reverse proxy on NGINX. When I'm trying to calculate rps, when I send requests to Go server everything is OK, but NGINX returns many 502 error. What could be the problem?

OS - MacOs with M2
8083 port - GO
8082 port - NGINX

**Requests to GO**

hey -h2 -n 20000 -c 100 http://localhost:8083/album

```
Total:  1.8949 secs
Status code distribution:
  [200] 20000 responses
```

**PROBLEM:**
**Requests to NGINX**
hey -h2 -n 20000 -c 100 http://localhost:8082/album

```
Total:  30.8949 secs
Status code distribution:
  [200] 16346 responses
  [502] 3653 responses
```

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}

server {
    listen 8082;
    server_name localhost;

    proxy_connect_timeout      15;
    proxy_send_timeout         15;
    proxy_read_timeout         15;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8083;
    }
}
```

```
andreichupin@kr2wd63p3q ~ % curl -v http://localhost:8082/album       
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8082...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET /album HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.25.3
< Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 20:39:05 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 231
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":"1","title":"Blue Train","artist":"John Coltrane","price":56.99},{"id":"2","title":"Jeru","artist":"Gerry Mulligan","price":17.99},{"id":"3","title":"Sarah Vaughan and Clifford Brown","artist":"Sarah Vaughan","price":39.99}]
```

Want to understand the reason of this behaviour.